# Проблемы и ошибки UNION

Tags: sql, mysql

Привет.
Везде пишут что рекомендовано объеденять столбци одинаковые по типу столбцу.

Сколько не проверял(даже строки пихал в колонку с int) у меня никаких ошибок не выдавало .
Может есть наглядный пример ,когда это вызывает ошибки?
Единственная ошибка это следить за количеством столбцов в выборке.
Кто-то может знает еще уязвимости?

Comment: @msi уже ответил, почему нет сообщения об ошибке. Но вот термин "уязвимость" тут несколько неуместен. Если Вы мешаете ужей и ежей, то это -- не уязвимость, а опасность уколоться о ежа при попытке достать ежа...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL неявно преобразует число к строковому типу, выполняя подобный запрос:

```
select 1
union
select 'a';
```

А вот SQL Server выдаст ошибку:

Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'a' to data type int.